# Find third coordinate for a right triangle with 45degree angles

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have a right triangle with two 45degree angles.

I know the points for the two coordinates opposite the right angle. I need to calculate the missing point.

I have seen similar questions here, but I have not understood the answers. There were lots of symbols and fancy words that made no sense to me. I tried to do some calculations, but my results are not quite right.

I'm hoping someone can provide me with a solution using layman's terms and a straight-forward formula.

Thanks very much

[image]

Comment: 1. What are the two points? 2. Where is your attempt? 3. Which angle is the right angle?

Comment: Do you know when straight lines are perpendicular?

Comment: @KennyLau The points will change. This is a dynamic situation. The points could be anywhere on the graph. 

The right angle is the angle opposite the two points I know.

Comment: Note that for a  given pair of points there will be two solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two given points are opposite corners of a square. The third point of the triangle will be one of the other two corners of this square. Since the diagonals of a square are the same length and perpendicular to each other, you can find these points by computing the midpoint of the two given points and then going out the same distance perpendicularly to either side of it.

Let the two given points be $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2=(x_2,y_2)$. Their midpoint is at $$P_0=P_1+\frac12(P_2-P_1)=\frac12(P_1+P_2)=\left({x_1+x_2\over2},{y_1+y_2\over2}\right).$$ Now we need a vector that's perpendicular to the line between $P_1$ and $P_2$ and has length equal to half the distance between them. $\frac12(P_2-P_1)=\left({x_2-x_1\over2},{y_2-y_1\over2}\right)$ has the right length, but is 90 degrees off, so we rotate that:$$\left(-{y_2-y_1\over2},{x_2-x_1\over2}\right).$$ Adding to and subtracting from $P_0$ gives you the points you’re looking for:$$\left({x_1+x_2\over2},{y_1+y_2\over2}\right)\pm\left(-{y_2-y_1\over2},{x_2-x_1\over2}\right).$$

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=(x_A,y_A)$ and $B=(x_B,y_B)$ be the given points. Let their midpoint be $M=((x_A+x_B)/2,(y_A+y_B)/2)$ and $X=(x,y)$ the point to be found.

Then you have that $MX$ is perpendicular to $AB$ and that $MX=AM$. This gives you two equations, to find $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I understand how you solved for M. I do not however understand the rest of your answer. I don't actually see a formula there.

Comment: How do I multiply coordinates?

Comment: $MX$ is not a multiplication, it is the length of segment $MX$. In coordinates: $MX=\sqrt{(x_M-x)^2+(y_M-y)^2}$. But if you don't understand even those basic things, it is quite hard to help you. I'm not going to give you the formula "ready to go", sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have ($W$ is auxiliary to write in a line the second equation) $$W=(X-x_1)^2+(Y-y_1)^2=(X-x_2)^2+(Y-y_2)^2\qquad (1)\\(X-\frac{x_1+x_2} {2})^2+(Y-\frac{y_1+y_2}{2})^2+(\frac {x_1+y_1}{2}-x_1)^2+(\frac {y_1+y_2}{2}-y_1)^2=W\qquad (2)$$
This simplifies to linear system
$$aX+bY=c\qquad (1')\\dX+eY=f\qquad (2')$$ Try to determine the values of the constants $a,b,c,d,e,f$ and solve the linear system.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer the question. However, I have to admit that I don't understand. What is W?

Comment: $W$ is just a notation to avoid equation $(2)$ be written in two lines (it means LHS of $(2)$=RHS of $(1)$).